# Using Preprocessor DATE dynamically

Tags: c++, c++builder, rad-studio

I'm trying to use `__DATE__` in C++Builder, and I need to use it dynamically.  For example, if a user click on a button, the label containing `__DATE__` will update following the system date.

I did that for now:

```
label1->Text = "Data: " __DATE__;
```

This is in a function to set the date, called `DateTime()`. For the button I already did the click event, but I need the `DateTime()` to run dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__DATE__` is a compile-time constant.  It is the date on which the `.cpp` file is compiled.  This is not what you want in this situation.

C++Builder's RTL has a [`Sysutils::Date()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Date) function that you can use instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>

label1->Text = _T("Data: ") + Date().DateString();
```

`Date()` returns a [`TDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TDateTime) representing the current system date (if you want to include time as well, use [`Sysutils::Now()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Now) instead).  Its [`DateString()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.TDateTime.DateString) method formats the `TDateTime` into a `String` using the user's locale settings.  If you want to format the `TDateTime` yourself, you can use its [`FormatString()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.TDateTime.FormatString) method for that, eg:

```cpp
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>

label1->Text = _T("Data: ") + Date().FormatString(_T("yyyy-mm-dd"));
or:
label1->Text = Date().FormatString(_T("'Data: 'yyyy-mm-dd"));
```

If you want a more standard C++ solution, look at the [`std::time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) and [`std:::strftime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) functions, eg:

```cpp
#include <ctime>

std::time_t now_c = std::time(nullptr);
std::tm now_tm = *std::localtime(&now_c);

char buffer[11] = {};
std::strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d", &now_tm);
    
label1->Text = _T("Data: ") + String(buffer);
or:
label1->Text = String().sprintf(_T("Data: %s"), buffer);
```

Or, look at the [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) library introduced in C++11, such as [`std::chrono::system_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock), eg:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::time_t now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
std::tm now_tm = *std::localtime(&now_c);

char buffer[11] = {};
std::strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d", &now_tm);
    
label1->Text = _T("Data: ") + String(buffer);
or:
label1->Text = String().sprintf(_T("Data: %s"), buffer);
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::time_t now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
std::tm now_tm = *std::localtime(&now_c);

std::wostringstream oss;
oss << L"Data: " << std::put_time(&now_tm, L"%Y-%m-%d");

label1->Text = oss.str().c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`__DATE__` symbol is a pre-processor macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html), hence it is only defined at compile time.

That means that the actual value of `__DATE__` will not change during the execution of your program. It will be the time of your compilation. Forever the same value in the executable that you have just compiled.

If you need date string that reflects the current system clock/date, then you will need to use some function that queries the system for the current, as [`time()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/). Definitely not a compile-time-pre-processor macro string as `__DATE__`. See other [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/) functions to assist you in formatting the desired string.

Finally, about building the string: you will need to compose strings at runtime much as [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) does. Your construction `"Data: " __DATE__` is just valid because you are again concatenating string as compilation time (it is the compiler pre-processor the one doing the concatenation, no your program). [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#String_literal_concatenation) you can read about this capability of the C pre-processor. Also,[here](https://coderwall.com/p/z3ykww/compile-time-string-concatenation-in-c) is described that this is a C99 standard behaviour, but cannot tell if it was not defined in an earlier C standard.